# How to control for a numeric variable when doing a chi square goodness of fit test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm looking at race differences in the number of adverse events that happen at a hospital. At this hospital there are a lot more white people in general so I've been using a chi square goodness of fit test to see if there are more or less observed adverse events than what we would expect for each group.

Now I also have a third variable of hospital stay length which is numeric and there are significant differences in this between races. So how do I control this variable to do a statistical chi square goodness of fit?

Comment: You do the same thing where you calculate the expected value for each cell. The 2x2 idea extends to RxC tables.

Comment: Treat 'stay' as categorical 'less than 2', 3-5', ..., 'more than 30'. Or use a test meant for numerical variables.

Comment: Why are you using chi-square? This looks like a case for some sort of regression.

Answer (score 0):

Regression! The goal of regression is to cut down on variability. It's not fair to say that a person of race A had more adverse events during a hospital stay than a person of race B if the first person was in the hospital for weeks and the second person only spent a night.

$$Y_{adverse} = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{race} + \beta_2X_{length} $$

$X_{race}$ would be a binary indicator variable that is 0 for White and 1 for Black. (If you're comparing multiple races (White vs Black vs Hispanic vs Asian, for instance), then the situation changes but still can be handled by regression.)

You then would check for the significance of $\beta_1$.